# Is there an official mobile app on Windows Phone for Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

Currently using Windows Phone 8.1. I downloaded "Stackoverflow Lite" but I'm not sure if it is the official app. I do not want to give my data to unsafe sites.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Questions about StackOverflow itself belong on [meta].

Comment: StackOverflow lite is certainly NOT the official version. You'll find that there is no StackOverflow app - if there is an app, it'll be the StackExchange app, which contains all of the websites in the family.

Comment: Relevant Meta SE question: [Official Stack Exchange application for Windows Phone OS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225624/150283)